# Unable to link "react-native-background-timer" package for android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer

Using react native cli 0.62 to build an android app which requires a background timer. So, I am using the above package. Autolinking fails so trying the android manual linking procedure as mentioned in the above package's readme.

1. I am supposed to add in android/app/build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
+   implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
}
```

but my existing file looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

2. I am supposed to add in android/app/src/main/java/com/your-app/MainApplication.java :

```
+ import com.ocetnik.timer.BackgroundTimerPackage;

@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
+   new BackgroundTimerPackage()
  );
}
```

But my existing file looks like this :

```
@Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }
```

How do I include both the code sections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two build.gradle in android project. You have opened root level **android/build.gradle** file. You have to add the dependency in app level **android/app/build.gradle**. App level build.gradle file will have a dependency section at the end.

For the second part you have import the package after this uncomment this line and modify like this:

packages.add(new BackgroundTimerPackage());

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Alos, I didn't need to add the code in MainApplication.java . When I added it it says an error that it has been added twice (maybe once by autolinking) so I removed it.